# How do I insert an amazon search widget into posts or pages?

Tags: widgets, scripts

How do I insert an Amazon Search Widget into posts or pages? The source code is:

```
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws-cn.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CN&ID=V20070822%2FCN%2Fsparkandshine-23%2F8002%2F44f4fce5-23dd-4112-ab47-7ad500ef1fe3"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A rel="nofollow" HREF="http://ws-cn.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?rt=tf_sw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CN&ID=V20070822%2FCN%2Fsparkandshine-23%2F8002%2F44f4fce5-23dd-4112-ab47-7ad500ef1fe3&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.cn Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
```

---

**EDIT:**

The reason why the widget doesn't appear after embeded the above code into HTML is that the widget is blocked by **AdBlock**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're best bet is to put the amazon javascript script code into a widget, and then add the widget into a post/page using a shortcode.  Give a look at this plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/

(I've never used it, but the concept seems correct.)